# (python) ERROR: attempted use of x = input("string") causes errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, google-chrome, chromebook

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "p.py", line 1, in <module>
x = input("hello")
File "<string>", line 0  

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I get this error when i input the following code into my script:

```
x = input("press enter to continue")
```

and the same when i input this:

```
input("press enter to continue")
```

and again:

```
input('press enter to continue')
```

i am running linux on a chrome acer with linux beta. it uses python 3. what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using python 3?

Comment: i typed python 3 into the terminal and it worked then, but not as part of a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using Python 2, not Python 3. Replace `input` with `raw_input`:

`x = raw_input("press enter to continue")`

---

This is why I believe you're using Python 2. My test with Python 3 (notice there's no error):

```
Python 3.7.6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = input("press enter to continue")
press enter to continue
>>>
```

And then I see the same error that you get when using Python 2:

```
Python 2.7.17
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = input("press enter to continue")
press enter to continue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>> x = raw_input("press enter to continue")
press enter to continue
>>>
```

Comment: there is a difference between when i run in terminal and when i run in script

Comment: @joshuarobbins can you show us the rest of the script then?

Comment: literally just this line: input("continue")

Comment: based on your comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622005/python-error-attempted-use-of-x-inputstring-causes-errors/61622378?noredirect=1#comment109003635_61622328) you are using Python 2.7.13, so your script will work if you change `input` to use `raw_input`

Comment: it turned out that the IDE was not picking up on the updated python version, which caused errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try raw_input() rather than input()

Comment: `raw_input` is for python 2. He is using python 3.

Comment: it actually worked. how do you check what it is using, as i thought i installed python 3

Comment: I believe he is using python 2.7 other else he would not have gotten this error.

Comment: type this into the terminal :     python --version                                                             then type this:     python3 --version